# Covert a column of integers and interger + strings into all integers using multiplication based on what is in the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I convert this column of values, mostly integers, and some strings to all integers.

The column looks like this,

```
x1
___
128455551
92571902
123125
985166
np.NaN
2241
1.50000MMM
2.5255MMM
1.2255MMMM
np.NaN
...
```

And I want it to look like this, where the rows with MMM, the characters are dropped and the number is multiplied by a billion (10**9) and converted to integers.

The rows where there are MMMM, the characters are dropped and the number is multiplied by a trillion (10**12) and converted to integers.

Basically each M means 1,000. There are other columns so I cannot drop the `np.NaN`.

```
x1
___
128455551
92571902
123125
985166
np.NaN
2241
1500000000
2525500000
1225500000000
np.NaN
...
```

I tried this,

```
df['x1'] =np.where(df.x1.astype(str).str.contains('MMM'), (df.x1.str.replace('MMM', '').astype(float) * 10**9).astype(int), df.x1)
```

When I do it with just the 2 rows it works fine, but when I do it with the whole dataframe I get this error, `IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`.

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        ms = x.count('M')
        return float(x.replace('M' * ms, '')) * 10**(3 * ms)
    else:
        return x

df['x1'] = df['x1'].map(f).astype('Int64')
```

Output:

```
              x1
0      128455551
1       92571902
2         123125
3         985166
4           <NA>
5           2241
6     1500000000
7     2525500000
8  1225500000000
9           <NA>
```

Comment: Glad to see you again Paul and Merry Christmas to you :)

Comment: Glad to see you too, @AnoushiravanR! Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!

Comment: Paul have you also shifted to Python recently? I think I remember you with your contributions to R questions.

Comment: I had to learn Python for professional reasons and that is why I am here trying to answer Python questions, @AnoushiravanR -- to me, answering questions here is the best way to learn a new language.. I have not had time to contribute to the R forum, unfortunately. But since I love R, I will be returning to the R forum someday.

Comment: Yes I understand, that was the case with me to. I started learning Python since last Christmas and so far I have enjoyed this great learning experience. But I have to admit, R is the more flexible of the 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

(df.x1.str.extract('([^M]+)(M+)?').replace({np.NaN : None})
 .assign(power = lambda x: 10 ** (3 * x.loc[:, 1].str.count('M').fillna(0)))
 .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[:, 0].replace({'np.NaN' : None}).astype(float).mul(d.power)))


0    1.284556e+08
1    9.257190e+07
2    1.231250e+05
3    9.851660e+05
4             NaN
5    2.241000e+03
6    1.500000e+09
7    2.525500e+09
8    1.225500e+12
9             NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

When considering  string values containing `M`, sanitized value can be multiplied on `1000` as much as `M` occurrences (according to your condition *"Basically each M means 1,000"*):

```
df['x1'] = np.where(df.x1.str.contains('M'),
                    (df.x1.str.replace('M', '').astype(float) \
                     * pow(1000, df.x1.str.count('M'))).astype('Int64'), df.x1)

print(df)
```

---

```
              x1
0      128455551
1       92571902
2         123125
3         985166
4            NaN
5           2241
6     1500000000
7     2525500000
8  1225500000000
9            NaN
```

Comment: i get this error `TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64`

Comment: @anarchy, I got no errors for above code on `pandas` 1.5